# Extract pdf pages which contains an image

Tags: python, pdf

I have a number of pdf files in which some pages contain images and others not. Is there a way to extract only those pages of the pdf which contains an image? Unfortunately, its not sufficient to simply extract the images. I need to make sure that the whole page that contains the image is extracted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cpdf -image-resolution 10000 in.pdf` will list all images in the file. You can then extract the page numbers from the appropriate column of the output. You then do, for example `cpdf in.pdf 63 -o p63.pdf` for example to extract the given page.